# Why was the Stack Exchange engine once for sale but no longer is?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-history

There has long been plenty of interest in Stack Exchange clones. We even have a question cataloging them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones).

I never thought much about why the Stack Exchange technology isn't for sale. Who knows, maybe the team just doesn't feel like selling their secret sauce.

Then I saw an [interesting comment in an answer by ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87337/stack-exchange-for-a-new-purpose):

> The team doesn't sell the system for "public" use any more. SE 1.0 was an attempt at that which failed.

What's the story behind this?

Comment: Note that the Stack Exchange engine [is ostensibly still for sale for internal enterprise use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16055/139837).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not much of a story - there wasn't much interest in the "Stack Exchange" platform as a product.

There were a few sites that were created and most of them didn't gain any traction - turns out that to have a thriving Q&A site, you need a community behind it (that's the philosophy behind Area 51 proposals - show us there is a community, and it will get a chance at a Stack Exchange site).

Simply put - it wasn't a commercial success and was therefore abandoned.

---

This has somewhat changed now (mid 2016) - we do sell the engine to large organizations these days. [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available-for-use/197549#197549) is now a thing - to find out more, you can contact **enterprise [at] stackoverflow .com**.

Comment: The few SE1.0 sites that *were* successful have for the most part been folded back into the network, too.