# New Migration Path to Network Engineering

Tags: feature-request, migration

In response to this question [How can we improve moderation of IP networking questions on Stack Overflow and associated sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88047/how-can-we-improve-moderation-of-ip-networking-questions-on-stack-overflow-and-araises)

Perhaps we should add a migration path to [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) from StackOverflow to redirect questions that fall into this category.

As this site is still in Beta I am unsure of the policy towards migrating topics to it but I would think redirecting traffic there would benefit both of the sites.

Current [Migration Path List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider that SO doesn't really get all that many relevant questions and that space is dear in that popup. There are *better* destinations.

Additionally, as a beta site, we discourage migrations, as for a beta site we don't want it to be inundated by posts other sites don't want.

Answer (score 2):

There was [one question in the last 90 days](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) migrated to Network Engineering.

Compare this to the current options:

- Meta Stack Overflow 84
- Super User 1,370
- Tex 140
- DBA 491
- Sharepoint 57

There doesn't seem to be any need to do this.

The only site that has more than any of these is Code Review, which is also a beta site, with 71 migrations. This should be considered over Network Engineering.

Comment: That link is 10k+ but I take your word for it.